# fullpage.js not working properly with anchor links

Tags: javascript

I was trying to do a full page scroll while using anchor links throughout the page but sometimes it won't scroll up anymore or the links stop working or go to the wrong places. It gets pushed down leaving strange white space after I scroll around an press on the links.

Link to code:
https://codepen.io/serelath/pen/NEzyxL

I appreciate it if anyone can look into this for me.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    /*[pan and well CSS scrolls]*/
    var pnls = document.querySelectorAll('.panel').length,
        scdir, hold = false;

    function _scrollY(obj) {
        var slength, plength, pan, step = 100,
            vh = window.innerHeight / 100,
            vmin = Math.min(window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth) / 100;
        if ((this !== undefined && this.id === 'well') || (obj !== undefined && obj.id === 'well')) {
            pan = this || obj;
            plength = parseInt(pan.offsetHeight / vh);
        }
        if (pan === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        plength = plength || parseInt(pan.offsetHeight / vmin);
        slength = parseInt(pan.style.transform.replace('translateY(', ''));
        if (scdir === 'up' && Math.abs(slength) < (plength - plength / pnls)) {
            slength = slength - step;
        } else if (scdir === 'down' && slength < 0) {
            slength = slength + step;
        } else if (scdir === 'top') {
            slength = 0;
        }
        if (hold === false) {
            hold = true;
            pan.style.transform = 'translateY(' + slength + 'vh)';
            setTimeout(function() {
                hold = false;
            }, 500);
        }
        console.log(scdir + ':' + slength + ':' + plength + ':' + (plength - plength / pnls));
    }
    /*[swipe detection on touchscreen devices]*/
    function _swipe(obj) {
        var swdir,
            sX,
            sY,
            dX,
            dY,
            threshold = 100,
            /*[min distance traveled to be considered swipe]*/
            slack = 50,
            /*[max distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction]*/
            alT = 300,
            /*[max time allowed to travel that distance]*/
            elT, /*[elapsed time]*/
            stT; /*[start time]*/
        obj.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
            var tchs = e.changedTouches[0];
            swdir = 'none';
            sX = tchs.pageX;
            sY = tchs.pageY;
            stT = new Date().getTime();
            //e.preventDefault();
        }, false);

        obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); /*[prevent scrolling when inside DIV]*/
        }, false);

        obj.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
            var tchs = e.changedTouches[0];
            dX = tchs.pageX - sX;
            dY = tchs.pageY - sY;
            elT = new Date().getTime() - stT;
            if (elT <= alT) {
                if (Math.abs(dX) >= threshold && Math.abs(dY) <= slack) {
                    swdir = (dX < 0) ? 'left' : 'right';
                } else if (Math.abs(dY) >= threshold && Math.abs(dX) <= slack) {
                    swdir = (dY < 0) ? 'up' : 'down';
                }
                if (obj.id === 'well') {
                    if (swdir === 'up') {
                        scdir = swdir;
                        _scrollY(obj);
                    } else if (swdir === 'down' && obj.style.transform !== 'translateY(0)') {
                        scdir = swdir;
                        _scrollY(obj);

                    }
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            }
        }, false);
    }
    /*[assignments]*/
    var well = document.getElementById('well');
    well.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
    well.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
        if (e.deltaY < 0) {
            scdir = 'down';
        }
        if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            scdir = 'up';
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    well.addEventListener('wheel', _scrollY);
    _swipe(well);
    var tops = document.querySelectorAll('.top');
    for (var i = 0; i < tops.length; i++) {
        tops[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            scdir = 'top';
            _scrollY(well);
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Could you describe exactly step by step how to reproduce your problem? Thanks.